# Implement HTTP 302 response with libmicrohttpd in C

Tags: c, http, redirect, request, webserver

I'm wondering how to implement a 302 redirect with libmicrohttpd in C. I know the response should be MHD_HTTP_FOUND but I am not sure how to pass the Location:... to be redirected. I've searched and haven't found much on this; is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: It's .htaccess for redirect http errors, no ? O.o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [response headers tutorial](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/tutorial.html#Response-headers) you'll need to create a response object and add the location header like:

```
struct MHD_Response *response;
// Create response object
MHD_add_response_header (response, "Location", "http://somesite.com/page.html");
MHD_queue_response (connection, MHD_HTTP_OK, response);
```

Also see the [libmicrohttpd response header documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/manual/libmicrohttpd.html#microhttpd_002dresponse-headers) for more details.